# Apt: remove all unused manual packages

Tags: apt, package-management

how to use apt to remove all unused manual packages.

yes, i have tried autoremove but it only removed unused automatic packages

Comment: That would be a complete uninstallation of your whole system. I.e. the fact that your system boots is because the base system packages were installed "manually". How should apt know what of that you're using and what not?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us some more details. For example, your operating system could be relevant. Then, explain what exactly you mean by "unused".

Comment: @Marcus not quite, packages which are required for basic functionality of the system (booting and being able to install other packages) are protected by their “Essential” flag, not by being marked as manually installed.

Comment: @StephenKitt true, my mistake (can't edit comments), what I meant was what is typically the job of whatsitcalled `dpkg-select`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to mark all packages as automatically installed:

```
aptitude markauto '~i'
```

Do be warned that this will leave your system with only `Essential` packages, which might not be what you want.  I recommend using the `--schedule-only` option, then reviewing in an interactive `aptitude` session.